# Ionic LinkedIn cordova authentication bad redirect

Tags: angularjs, cordova, authentication, ionic-framework

I am trying to login using LinkedIn. I manage to get the accesstoken but for a split second before redirecting to the page I tell it to, i see this error

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>   The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

and this is the link

> http://localhost:80/callback?code=****&state=WQ7IIHGw

while Ionic works on my localhost:8100, I have set the the Authorized rediect URLS to **http://localhost/callback** in the linked in developer page

Also, 
when I set the linked in redirect URL to anything but the  localhost/call back i get this error

> Invalid redirect_uri. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key.

Answer (score 3):

Follow/verify this steps:

**Setup LinkedIn account developer options:** https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps/
After adding application go to its settings:

1. In Authentication Keys you will get `Client ID` and `Client Secret`
2. In Authorized Redirect URLs you must put: http://localhost/callback since it will be used by `$cordovaOauth`
3. Save/update account settings

**Setup Ionic app:**

4. Install [cordovaOauth](https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth) `bower install ng-cordova-oauth -S`
5. Add `<script src="lib/ng-cordova-oauth/dist/ng-cordova-oauth.js"></script>` to `index.html` and `'ngCordovaOauth'`to `apps.js`
6. Add `$cordovaOauth` to controller dependency
7. Add function to controller (only  `Client ID` and `Client Secret` need to be replaced by the data from LinkedIn dev account):

   ```
     $scope.linkedInLoginIonic = function () {
           var linkedinUriApi = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(email-address,first-name)?format=json&oauth2_access_token=";
           $cordovaOauth.linkedin("Client ID", "Client Secret", ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress'])
               .then(function (success) {
                       // Here you will get the access_token
                       console.log('Granted access to linkedin');
                       console.log(JSON.stringify(success));
                       // In request below my default header is disabled - otherwise Linkedin API will reject request
                       $http(
                           {method: 'GET',
                               url: linkedinUriApi + success.access_token,
                               headers: {Authorization: undefined}
                           }).then(function (response) {
                           console.log(response);
                       }, function (error) {
                           console.log(error);
                           console.log('Ionic LinkedIn API request after successful login failed');
                       });
                   },
                   function (error) {
                       console.log(error);
                   });
       };
   ```

**Tips:**

- request can be done only through device or emulator - in web browser you will get in console: `Cannot authenticate via a web browser`
- if you have default headers then disable it when requesting LinkedIn API (after authentication go well)
- if request after successful authentication fail check if scopes matches for all:

  - API request: here we ask for `address` and `first-name` in `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(email-address,first-name)?`
  - scope set when authenticating, see in example `$cordovaOauth` part `['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress']`
  - scope set in LinkedIn developer account
  - do final API request with minimal scope (i.e. only email)
- remember to debug emulator/device request so you will see where the problem is in your request/headers comparing it to values specified in https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2